# is there a method to query list of unique B Object inside object A from MongoDb using Spring boot

Tags: mongodb, list, spring-boot, nosql

we have

```
class A{

@id
int id;

List <B> bs;

}
```

where

```
class B{

 String prId;

 int pr;

}
```

i need a way to get list of B without duplication using prId.
so please suggest a way to get

```
[
{
prId: "18876",
pr: 1228876
},
{
prId: "123",
pr: 1228876
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions (or more)

1. change `List<B> bs;` to `Set<B> bs;` and make sure class B has and equal/hashcode method base only on the `prId`
2. Since B is and embedded list of document (B does not have its on collection), there is no id created when you save A, you can generate a mongo id (ObjectId) on save of A by yourself like this

```
class B{
 @Id
 String prId;
 int pr;
 // get set
}
B b = new B();
b.setPrId(ObjectId.get().toString());
```

then by retreiving A all Bs are suppose to be unique